# Polymorphic Paperclip Plugin with multiple picture uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-plugins, polymorphism

I have used paperclip polymorphic plugin to track my attachments. The tutorialwhich I have been through has used single attachments(image) http://burm.net/2008/10/17/ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-paperclip-plugin-tutorial/.

How do i enable multiple images with this plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make some changes to the code.

```
<p>
  Attach a file or image <br />
  <%= f.file_field :data%>
</p>
```

The upper code should be

```
<%= file_field_tag 'model[data][]'%>
<%= file_field_tag 'model[data][]'%>
```

This will allow you to add 2 images.

Hope this helps.